# "Backspace" over last character written to file

Tags: python

I have a Python application which outputs an SQL file:

```
sql_string = "('" + name + "', " + age + "'),"
output_files['sql'].write(os.linesep + sql_string)
output_files['sql'].flush()
```

This is not done in a `for` loop, it is written as data becomes available. Is there any way to 'backspace' over the last comma character when the application is done running, and to replace it with a  semicolon? I'm sure that I could invent some workaround by outputting the comma before the newline, and using a global Bool to determine if any particular 'write' is the first write. However, I think that the application would be much cleaner if I could just 'backspace' over it. Of course, being Python maybe there is such an easier way!

Note that having each `insert` value line in a list and then imploding the list is not a viable solution in this use case.

Comment: You don't really want to go there; you'd rather keep your output file very generic, so that it could be a pipe, named pipe, an object representing a TCP connection or a HTTP post field, etc. Some of these have side effects and you cannot take back the last character.

Comment: @qarma: Thank you. In the specific case where my 'output file' is not generic but rather a text file as I've described, are there any 'side effects' that I should be wary of? Note that this will be running on a Debian-derived OS. Additionally, I'm not sure why I would rather keep my output file very generic, perhaps you could elucidate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use seek to move your cursor one byte (character) backwards, then write the new character:

```
f.seek(-1, os.SEEK_CUR)
f.write(";")
```

This is the easiest change, maintaining your current code ("working code" beats "ideal code") but it would be better to avoid the situation.

Comment: +1 for hack. I imagine this only works for binary files. If file is opened in text mode and last character was complex unicode, I doubt `seek` knows how many bytes to roll back.

Comment: Thank you, this may be feasible. In fact, the files are opened as `a+` (it is expected that they do not exist prior). The 'last character' will always be the comma. Is this safe?

Comment: Somewhat safe, yes. Somewhat ugly, yes.

Answer (score 4):

How about adding the commas before adding the new line?

```
first_line = True

...

sql_string = "('" + name + "', " + age + "')"

if not first_line:
    output_files['sql'].write(",")
first_line = False

output_files['sql'].write(os.linesep + sql_string)
output_files['sql'].flush()

...

output_files['sql'].write(";")
output_files['sql'].flush()
```

You did mention this in your question - I think this is a much clearer to a maintainer than seeking commas and overwriting them.

EDIT: Since the above solution would require a global boolean in your code (which is not desirable) you could instead wrap the file writing behaviour into a helper class:

```
class SqlFileWriter:

    first_line = True

    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.f = open(file_name)

    def write(self, sql_string):
        if not self.first_line:
            self.f.write(",")
        self.first_line = False

        self.f.write(os.linesep + sql_string)
        self.f.flush()

    def close(self):
        self.f.write(";")
        self.f.close()


output_files['sql'] = SqlFileWriter("myfile.sql")
output_files['sql'].write("('" + name + "', '" + age + "')")
```

This encapsulates all the SQL notation logic into a single class, keeping the code readable and at the same time simplifying the caller code.

Comment: Thank you. The problem with this approach is maintaining the global `bool` which is not feasible in this particular application.

Comment: I've updated my answer to suggest how you could avoid a global `bool` by wrapping the file operations in a helper class.

Comment: Thank you Sean. When I get to the stage that I can start deploying new features to the code, I will handle it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file to write as binary: 'wb' instead of 'w'.

Answer (score 0):

Use generators, e.g.:

```
def with_separator(data, sep):
    first = True:
    for datum in data:
        if first:
            first = False
        else:
            yield sep
        yield datum

with open("sdfasdfas", "w") as outf:
    for x in with_separator(sql_get_rows(), ",\n"):
        outf.write(x)
        # flush if needed
```

For hardcore iterator use, this should get you started:

```
In [11]: list( itertools.imap("".join, itertools.izip(itertools.chain([""], itertools.repeat(",\n")), "abc")) )
Out[11]: ['a', ',\nb', ',\nc']
```

If your data uses imperative API, that is not iterable, `send()` your data to generator:

```
def write_with_separator(filename, sep):
    with file(filename, "w"):
        first = True
        yield None
        while True:
            datum = yield None
            if first:
                first = False
            else:
                fout.write(sep)
            fout.write(datum)
            # flush if needed

writer = write_with_separator("somefilename", ",\n")
writer.next()  # can't send to just-started generator

# to be called when you get data
for row in sql_get_rows():
    writer.send(row)
```

Comment: Thank you qarma. However, for the same reason that I cannot maintain a global bool to know if I'm on the 'first_output', a generator will not help either. I did mention in the OP that exploding a dictionary is not a feasible solution for this use case.